# XNA Combo moves.

Tags: xna, xna-4.0

I am working on a tutorial part for my game for moves.

Each move requires 1 or more keyboard keys to be pressed.
Once the move is pressed, the next move to be pressed is displayed on the screen.

How do I go about creating predefined lists of these and cycle through them based on whether last one is correctly input? (I've got a few pretty long sequences... should I code them in XML, etc? It's a game based on combo sequences. How about creating some type of system for it?

Any advice or advice on a good tutorial would be much appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: XML or JSON sounds like a decent candidate if you're just trying to keep track of static lists. You should have other ways to detect when a combo is correctly input (when the combo itself actually fires), so just piggy back on that and compare the combo that just occurred with the combo that is currently being displayed, and if they're the same, increment the list.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't you create an array of `Keys` objects:

```
Keys[] TutorialMove = new Keys[6];    // <- 7 Key Stroke Combo for move
```

And then populate it or:

```
Keys[] TutorialMove = {
    Keys.Left,
    Keys.Up,
    Keys.Space
    }
// A three combo move in that order.
```

And then you could call this with:

```
short Strokes = 0;
short MoveLen = TutorialMove.Length();
public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
// Hopefully you already created this variable in Initialize()
currentKeyboardState = Keyboard.GetState();

if (currentKeyboardState.IsKeyDown(TutorialMove[Strokes]))
    {
    Strokes += 1;
    if (Strokes == MoveLen)
        {
        // End Tutorial (or change move sequence)
        }
    }
}
```

And that should do what you want. That way, you can easily define your combo's as a list in the format of the second suggestion. Or write the Key Presses in a text file, and make a method to read them and assign the to you array.

Hope this helped, Mona.